# Trying to update a Sencha Touch extended panel after html has changed

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4

Im pulling some data out of my webdb, turning it into html and wanting to bind that to the html property of an extended xtype:

```
App.views.Homecard = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
title: "Home",
iconCls: "home",
defaults: {
    styleHtmlContent: true
},
items: [{
        title: 'TabPanels',
        scroll: 'vertical', 
        html: getPresentations
        },
        {
        title: 'Toolbars',
        scroll: 'vertical', 
        html: '<p>Toolbars can be used as a title bar or as a '
        }],
```

});

SEE THE 'html: returnHTML' -- this variable is getting built in a webdb callback.. I would like to call a refresh or an update on this page after I get that string done.. can someone help me with how?

Thanks!
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get a reference to the item object. You can do this in many ways and it depends on where you get the `differentHTML` object. Let say you modify your code like this so you can get the item object by id.

```
{
id: 'parent'
title: "Home",
iconCls: "home",
defaults: {
    styleHtmlContent: true
}
```

Then use the following code to get to the item that needs to change it's HTML. Afterwards call `doLayout` and `doComponentLayout()` since the different HTML probably takes different space.

```
var item = Ext.getCmp('parent').items.items[0];
     item.update(differentHTML);
     item.doLayout();
     Ext.getCmp('parent').doComponentLayout();
```

Note that this is a sort of hack. Normally what I would do is first have a model defined that will hold the data you are getting from your webdb. Then have a controller that will update the HTML by applying to a template. This way you can get reference to the item much easier and without the need of id. Also you can maintain much cleaner code by separating the formatting code from the actual data. 
You can start learning more about this with the following video: http://www.sencha.com/learn/xtemplates-part-i/.

Live example http://jsfiddle.net/p5K4q/34/

Comment: hey can you take a look at my code again above... i hadnt got it all copied the first time.  I was following along with one of the tute videos - so would your advice still apply to the way I am doing it above?  I am not used to model/view/controller thing at all..thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes it would apply. MVC is only a recommendation, you don't need to follow. Just add `id` property to the `App.views.Homecard` object and then update the html with the code above (this code ->`var item = Ex....`).

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working...:

Preeze.views.Homecard = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {    
    id: "Parent",
    title: "Home",
    iconCls: "home",
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    html: "adfdasf"    
});

Ext.reg('homecard', Preeze.views.Homecard);

var item = Ext.getCmp('Parent').items.items[0];

item is Undefined... Ext.getCmp('Parent') cannot find anything...?

Comment: When do you call that `Ext.getCmp('Parent')` ? You need to call it after the view has be rendered.